# When attempting to insert data into an existing table I get the following error message "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1"

Tags: sql-server

Below is the script for the Table(s) columns,code and error messages, please advise.

Customer Table

```
Customer_Number int default NULL,
Last_Name varchar(255) default NULL,
First_Name varchar(255) default NULL,
Address varchar(255) default NULL,
City varchar(255),
State varchar(50) default NULL,
Zip_Code varchar(255),
Phone_Number varchar(100) default NULL,
Fax_Number varchar(100) default NULL,
Email_Address varchar(255) default NULL,

INSERT INTO CustomerTable (Customer_Number,Last_Name,First_Name,Address,City,State,Zip_Code,Phone_Number,Fax_Number,Email_Address)

VALUES 
(1,"Jimenez","Colette","Ap #871-5401 Erat, Rd.","College","AK","70453","(172) 438-0029","(245) 956-3423","magna@gravida.org"),
(3,"Bradford","George","P.O. Box 456, 6105 Lectus Av.","Metairie","LA","67131","(830) 888-9319","(868) 825-4029","Aliquam.nec.enim@a.co.uk"),
(5,"Sargent","Portia","292-790 Nam Rd.","Savannah","GA","13313","(674) 480-9590","(721) 767-4086","natoque.penatibus@nonenimMauris.edu"),
(7,"Lamb","Donna","999-1321 Semper. St.","Auburn","ME","46944","(708) 991-8901","(448) 255-6118","pretium.neque.Morbi@egestaslacinia.org"),
(9,"Simmons","Clementine","P.O. Box 466, 3790 Hendrerit Rd.","Newark","DE","45138","(963) 886-1067","(897) 776-7930","tristique.senectus.et@duiinsodales.co.uk"),
(11,"Nieves","Emily","818-2713 Erat, Rd.","Racine","WI","03676","(431) 679-7182","(462) 890-7721","tellus@ornaresagittisfelis.ca"),
(13,"Shepherd","Lunea","P.O. Box 497, 6066 Non St.","Boise","ID","95963","(828) 558-1055","(970) 684-6478","Duis.cursus.diam@rhoncus.edu"),
(15,"Sexton","Inez","8814 Est Ave","Iowa City","IA","13647","(407) 893-2889","(357) 393-4996","est@atauctorullamcorper.org"),
(17,"Bernard","Delilah","996-1230 Lorem, Ave","Hartford","CT","79198","(597) 475-4749","(667) 399-8586","Cras.vulputate.velit@mauris.net"),
(19,"Crane","Gloria","7259 Dignissim St.","Pocatello","ID","85610","(491) 517-0453","(483) 177-8639","dignissim@tortordictum.edu"),
(21,"Mcclure","Dominic","3849 Id Street","Worcester","MA","80962","(486) 612-3100","(733) 152-9681","Cras@convallisantelectus.org"),
(23,"Hewitt","Eugenia","5263 Lectus. Rd.","Waterbury","CT","79581","(444) 874-7690","(594) 465-3862","vulputate.posuere@nonummyut.com"),
(25,"Montoya","Rose","632-7686 Diam Avenue","Miami","FL","36791","(468) 371-8873","(201) 970-8490","Sed.molestie.Sed@nonsollicitudin.org"),
(27,"Fisher","Rae","5324 Pellentesque. Avenue","Springfield","IL","01248","(933) 281-7202","(989) 825-9187","In.nec.orci@enimcondimentum.co.uk"),
(29,"Beck","Kimberley","Ap #568-2961 A Rd.","Green Bay","WI","08599","(125) 832-9763","(723) 392-8378","posuere@urna.net"),
(31,"Casey","Denton","P.O. Box 884, 2684 Vitae Rd.","Pike Creek","DE","08476","(832) 626-8235","(844) 648-4321","risus.at.fringilla@mauris.ca"),
(33,"Bridges","Kessie","394-1626 Vivamus St.","Norman","OK","42127","(946) 242-0298","(146) 348-7903","at.auctor@sagittis.org"),
(35,"Holloway","Jada","893-2773 A St.","Norman","OK","39953","(861) 667-9022","(468) 352-5913","mi.lacinia@mauris.edu"),
(37,"Oneil","Madaline","P.O. Box 253, 7281 Nec Avenue","Covington","KY","34165","(274) 182-1124","(338) 660-0705","parturient@afacilisis.net"),
(39,"Sims","Rylee","937-8330 Suspendisse Av.","Olympia","WA","61245","(178) 701-8803","(433) 306-6986","blandit@eumetus.ca")
```

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Jimenez'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Colette'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Ap #871-5401 Erat, Rd.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'College'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'AK'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '70453'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(172) 438-0029'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(245) 956-3423'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'magna@gravida.org'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Bradford'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'George'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'P.O. Box 456, 6105 Lectus Av.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Metairie'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'LA'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '67131'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(830) 888-9319'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(868) 825-4029'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Aliquam.nec.enim@a.co.uk'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Sargent'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Portia'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '292-790 Nam Rd.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Savannah'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'GA'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '13313'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(674) 480-9590'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(721) 767-4086'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'natoque.penatibus@nonenimMauris.edu'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Lamb'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Donna'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '999-1321 Semper. St.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Auburn'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'ME'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '46944'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(708) 991-8901'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(448) 255-6118'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'pretium.neque.Morbi@egestaslacinia.org'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Simmons'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Clementine'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'P.O. Box 466, 3790 Hendrerit Rd.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Newark'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'DE'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '45138'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(963) 886-1067'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(897) 776-7930'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'tristique.senectus.et@duiinsodales.co.uk'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Nieves'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Emily'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '818-2713 Erat, Rd.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Racine'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'WI'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '03676'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(431) 679-7182'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(462) 890-7721'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'tellus@ornaresagittisfelis.ca'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Shepherd'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Lunea'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'P.O. Box 497, 6066 Non St.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Boise'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'ID'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '95963'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(828) 558-1055'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(970) 684-6478'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Duis.cursus.diam@rhoncus.edu'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Sexton'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Inez'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '8814 Est Ave'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Iowa City'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'IA'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '13647'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(407) 893-2889'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(357) 393-4996'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'est@atauctorullamcorper.org'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Bernard'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Delilah'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '996-1230 Lorem, Ave'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Hartford'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'CT'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '79198'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(597) 475-4749'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(667) 399-8586'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Cras.vulputate.velit@mauris.net'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Crane'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Gloria'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '7259 Dignissim St.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Pocatello'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'ID'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '85610'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(491) 517-0453'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(483) 177-8639'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'dignissim@tortordictum.edu'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Mcclure'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Dominic'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '3849 Id Street'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Worcester'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'MA'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '80962'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(486) 612-3100'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(733) 152-9681'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Cras@convallisantelectus.org'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Hewitt'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Eugenia'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '5263 Lectus. Rd.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Waterbury'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'CT'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '79581'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(444) 874-7690'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(594) 465-3862'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'vulputate.posuere@nonummyut.com'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Montoya'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Rose'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '632-7686 Diam Avenue'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Miami'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'FL'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '36791'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(468) 371-8873'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(201) 970-8490'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Sed.molestie.Sed@nonsollicitudin.org'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Fisher'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Rae'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '5324 Pellentesque. Avenue'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Springfield'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'IL'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '01248'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(933) 281-7202'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(989) 825-9187'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'In.nec.orci@enimcondimentum.co.uk'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Beck'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Kimberley'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Ap #568-2961 A Rd.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Green Bay'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'WI'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '08599'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(125) 832-9763'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(723) 392-8378'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'posuere@urna.net'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Casey'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Denton'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'P.O. Box 884, 2684 Vitae Rd.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Pike Creek'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'DE'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '08476'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(832) 626-8235'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(844) 648-4321'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'risus.at.fringilla@mauris.ca'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Bridges'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Kessie'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '394-1626 Vivamus St.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Norman'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'OK'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '42127'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(946) 242-0298'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(146) 348-7903'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'at.auctor@sagittis.org'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Holloway'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Jada'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '893-2773 A St.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Norman'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'OK'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '39953'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(861) 667-9022'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(468) 352-5913'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'mi.lacinia@mauris.edu'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Oneil'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Madaline'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'P.O. Box 253, 7281 Nec Avenue'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Covington'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'KY'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '34165'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(274) 182-1124'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(338) 660-0705'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'parturient@afacilisis.net'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Sims'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Rylee'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '937-8330 Suspendisse Av.'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'Olympia'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'WA'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '61245'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(178) 701-8803'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name '(433) 306-6986'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid column name 'blandit@eumetus.ca'.

Comment: suggest minimising your sql statement eg. remove all but the first values in the insert ( the error should still be there ), then revise the post

Comment: Unless those email addresses are obfuscated or they don't mind being publicized as part of your quest for answers you should consider generisizing the question....and in the process shorten it as well

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes for text insert or SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON, identifiers can be delimited by double quotation marks, and literals must be delimited by single quotation marks. When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF, identifiers cannot be quoted and must follow all Transact-SQL rules for identifiers. For more information, see Database Identifiers. Literals can be delimited by either single or double quotation marks.

When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON (default), all strings delimited by double quotation marks are interpreted as object identifiers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx